# Does the order of conditions in an Oracle SQL statement matter?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Some of my coworkers make a point of ordering the conditions in Oracle SQL statements according to their understanding of the database and the presence of indices.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3152225/20571) dismisses the importance of sequence, while [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3152230/20571) has a comment that disagrees as far as PROLOG is concerned.

Okay, so ANSI SQL is really declarative and sequence is irrelevant. **How about Oracle 11?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you're still using the old rule-based optimizer (and since you've tagged your question oracle11g, you most definitely aren't), reordering the WHERE clauses makes virtually no difference.

Note my use of the term *virtually* because - according to [AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1857060700346051220) - they might still generate different execution plans if there are several operations that have the same estimated cost. But in practice, I'd consider it completely unnecessary to re-order the conditions in a SQL statement for performance reasons (it might still make sense to re-order them to make the statement more intelligible, of course).