# Sql - Explicit order of WHERE conditions?

Tags: sql

Is there any way to explicitly state the order for WHERE conditions to take place?  I realize that the query optimizer will look at all parts of the WHERE clause to determine the most efficient way to satisfy the query, as stated in these answers:

[Does order of where clauses matter in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436469/does-order-of-where-clauses-matter-in-sql)

[SQL - Does the order of WHERE conditions matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152182/sql-does-the-order-of-where-conditions-matter)

However, is there no way to check for a condition that other conditions will rely on? One of the answers from those threads touches on what I'm after, but doesn't offer a solution:

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where ISNUMERIC(table_name) = 1 and CAST(table_name as int) <> 0
```

This can fail because the CAST can be evaluated before determining whether the table_name field is numeric (and therefore throw an error for invalid casting).

Surely there must be a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a derived table:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT *
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
      WHERE ISNUMERIC(table_name)=1
     ) AS i
WHERE CAST(table_name AS INT)<>0
```

Alternatively, and most likely run in order, you can use a CASE statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE 0<>(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(table_name)=1 
          THEN CAST(table_name AS INT)
          ELSE 0 END)
```

---

It should be noted that for SQL Server there exist situations where the CASE-trick will fail. See the [documentation on CASE, Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql#remarks):

> The CASE statement evaluates its conditions sequentially and stops with the first condition whose condition is satisfied. **In some situations, an expression is evaluated before a CASE statement receives the results of the expression as its input. Errors in evaluating these expressions are possible.** Aggregate expressions that appear in WHEN arguments to a CASE statement are evaluated first, then provided to the CASE statement. For example, the following query produces a divide by zero error when producing the value of the MAX aggregate. This occurs prior to evaluating the CASE expression.
>
> ```
> WITH Data (value) AS 
> ( 
> SELECT 0 
> UNION ALL 
> SELECT 1 
> ) 
> SELECT 
>    CASE 
>       WHEN MIN(value) <= 0 THEN 0 
>       WHEN MAX(1/value) >= 100 THEN 1 
>    END 
> FROM Data ;
> ```

I suspect this might also be true for other RDBMS implementations.

Comment: Not pretty, but I'll take it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking if evaluation can short-circuit - it might help to read this:

[Is the SQL WHERE clause short-circuit evaluated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated)

So, you probably need to evaluate the first condition before attempting the second.  In MSSQL, you could use a CTE to do the first.  Or, another option might be to use a CASE to only perform the second under certain conditions.